# Redirect a menu item with htaccess when mod_rewrite is on (on WordPress)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a standard htaccess created by WordPress with permalinks on.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Now I need to have a category forwarding to another one.
So I tried:

```
Redirect /category/wood-framing/ http://www.mysite.com/category/wood-framing/framing/
```

This after the default rewrite above. But now I'm getting a redirect loop.
What's causing that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It isn't working because:

```
Redirect /category/wood-framing/ http://www.mysite.com/category/wood-framing/framing/
```

is telling it to redirect to `/category/wood-framing/framing/` if `/category/wood-framing/` is in the url, so when it redirects, it will run the rule again and since `/category/wood-framing/framing/` will still contain `/category/wood-framing/` it will start to do a loop.
This should work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/category/wood-framing/$
RewriteRule ^ /category/wood-framing/framing/ [R=301,L]
```